# How can I do this formula in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

My formula looks like this:

```
Conversion = Settled / (Settled + Cancelled)
```

How can I do this in a LINQ statement?

Here is my code:

```
WIP = g.Where(v => v.StatusCategoryID == 40).Sum(c => c.Amount) ?? 0,
Settled = g.Where(v => v.StatusCategoryID == 11).Sum(c => c.Amount) ?? 0,
Cancelled = g.Where(v => v.StatusCategoryID == 10).Sum(c => c.Amount) ?? 0,
```

Comment: Create two variables containing the sum for Settled and Cancelled and do the math? What's the StatusCategoryID == 40 for? Perhaps show a very small sample input and working code using `foreach()`.

Comment: This is a set of linq statements, so I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Also your syntax is invalid for the `where` clause.  What are all of those commas for?

Comment: Why do you need to do this *in linq* anyway? It not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @JNYRanger He's setting multiple variables.

Comment: @cubrr I realize that, but I don't want assume that this is inside of an object initializer considering they left that out.

Comment: All I need to do is the formula. The reason why I have comma's is because there are multiple parameters declared in my model which I need. I do not need to do this in LINQ, but it would be easier to

Comment: If you are trying to avoid looping over `g` three times, then the simplest solution is probably to just use a regular `foreach` loop. Sometimes linq is the right tool, sometimes it's not. Another alternative might be to do something using [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.100).aspx) perhaps returning `WIP`, `Settled` and `Cancelled` in one object?

Comment: *I do not need to do this in LINQ, but it would be easier to*: Well, clearly not, or you wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this with `Aggregate` (although it feels a little abusive):

```
var agg = g.Aggregate(new { wip = 0, settled = 0, cancelled = 0 }, (a, curr) => 
{
    return new 
    { 
        wip = a.wip + a.StatusCategoryID == 40 ? curr.Amount : 0, 
        settled = a.settled + a.StatusCategoryID == 11? curr.Amount : 0, 
        cancelled = a.cancelled + a.StatusCategoryID == 10? curr.Amount : 0, 
    };
});
```

And then you could just:

```
var Conversion = agg.settled / (agg.settled + agg.cancelled);
```

and:

```
var WIP = agg.wip;
```

The advantage here is that you've summed all three categories in just a single loop. I'm not sure that I find that much better than just using a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Of course, unless the original `IEnumerable` represents something like a database query, expensive deferred work, or something that doesn't always yield the same values when iterated, there isn't any reason to avoid iterating it multiple times in the first place, either with LINQ or without.